# Printing In Silverlight. Some pages missing

Tags: silverlight

I am maintaining an old application that prints checks from silverlight. 
The checks are in a grid and the user selects them and presses the print button.
I verified that all the checks selected in the grid do get sent to the printer but I noticed that sometimes some are missing in the actual printout. I check the EndPrint even for errors and there is none. 
How can I make sure all the data gets actually printed?

Here is the code for the printpage event

```
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
CheckInfo check = selectedChecks[printItemIndex];
PrintCheck printCheck = BuildPrintCheck(check);
stackPanel.Children.Add(printCheck);
stackPanel.Measure(new Size(args.PrintableArea.Width, double.PositiveInfinity));
if (++printItemIndex < selectedChecks.Count) 
       args.HasMorePages = true;

args.PageVisual = stackPanel;
```

Comment: What do you mean "all checks get sent to printer", but "missing in actual print out" . It's either one or the other?

Comment: I debug the code and verify that the data is being sent to the printer, but when I look at the physical pages, some pages are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it turned out that SilverLight5 (runtime) has an issue with printing images. The problem does not exist on clients running SilverLight4. 
Here is how I fixed it in my code

```
    private void PlaceImages()
        {

            var logoStreamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("myApp;/Images/logo.png", UriKind.Relative));
            var logo = new BitmapImage();
            logo.SetSource(logoStreamResourceInfo.Stream);
            var logoImageBrush = new ImageBrush();
            logoImageBrush.ImageSource = logo;
            upperLogo.Fill = logoImageBrush;
            lowerLogo.Fill = logoImageBrush;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to this issue posted here
http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2009/11/25/how-to-print-dynamically-created-images-in-silverlight-4-beta/

Basically instead of putting the Image straight into the page, put a Rectangle and and at run time load the image dynamically, set it as the image source for an image brush and then set the fill property  of the rectangle to the image brush.

Comment: Would you please include a few lines of sample code? The blog might not be permanent.